# How to minimize the Ram Memory of Spring Boot Apps?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have deployed multiple (7 apps) Spring boot apps on same server (4 GB RAM).
Each spring boot contains the following:

```
Eureka Client
Data JPA
AMQP (RabbitMQ)
Web, Webmvc
Actuator
Test
Devtools
```

Without Java OPTS (-Xmx and -Xss), each spring boot is taking 400MB-500MB memory (RAM). 
So I have added Java OPTS like below:

```
java -Xmx64m -Xss256k -jar test.jar
```

Now the memory (RAM) reduced to 200MB-300MB.

Can anyone guide me on decreasing the memory ?
Are the java opts and their sizes mentioned above fine ?

Comment: Have you done any memory profiling to see if you're unnecessarily keeping large swaths of data in memory for longer than you should be?

Comment: @Eugene I came to know that from my local windows system and linux server based on process Id

Comment: are you sure your app has started with `64MB` of heap?

Comment: @Eugene No, its taking beyond that

Comment: it's taking RAM beyond that... it seems you have a very vague understanding of JVM memory overall

Comment: @Eugene Please suggest how to minimize it.